# Prove that if sup($a_n$) = $\infty \Rightarrow$ $(a_n)_k \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, proof-writing

So i've looked and searched for some resource that might shed some light on this situation that I can actually understand, but I am sure there is something I missed. I've been on this question for hours:

## Prove that if sup($a_n$) = $\infty \Rightarrow$ $\exists b_k = a_{n_k} \to \infty$

So given $sup(a_n) = \infty $ then we know that $a_n$ has no upper bound.

Next we take some sub-sequence of $a_n$, such as $b_k = a_{n_k}$

Next we know the following *(I am pretty sure I need to get something like this, but am iffy on my logic of getting the following)*

$$a_{n_1} > n_1; a_{n_2} > n_2; \dots; a_{n_k} > n_k$$
$$\therefore b_k = a_{n_k} > k => b_k > k$$

Finally we show that $b_k \to \infty$ *little unsure on this logic now to and am pretty sure this isn't quite right.*

$$b_k > k => k \to \infty, b_k \to \infty$$

Just some remarks. I know that is proof is very likely wrong, especially at the points where I say $a_{n_1} > n_1$ *(Im sure I missing some statement for this to be true)*

and when I am proving $b_k \to \infty$ *(Not following the def of a limit)*

But this is the best I can think of.

Comment: You can write $a_{n_k}$ as a subsequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to show that there exists a subsequence $a_{n_k} \to +\infty$. We can do this easily. Note that $\sup_n a_n > 1$. Hence, there exists $n_1$ such that $a_{n_1} > 1$. Suppose that $a_{n_k} > k$ for each $k \leq N$. Then since $\sup_{n > n_N} a_n > N+ 1$, we have that there is some $n_{N+1} > n_N$ for which $a_{n_{N+1}} > N$. Thus, in this way, we construct inductively a sequence $a_{n_{k}} > k$ for all $k$, such that $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < \cdots$. Hence $a_{n_k}$ is a subsequence and $\liminf_k a_{n_k} \geq +\infty$, so $a_{n_k} \to +\infty$.

Comment: I am not clear on the notation $\sup_n a_n$, nor $\lim \inf_N b_N$ I get the $\sup a_n > N$ I also kind of get that $b_N > N$ but after I'm not sure.

Comment: I just modified my notation, hoping it is slightly clearer. The notation $\sup_n a_n$ means $\sup \{a_n\}$. To see such $b_N$ exists: suppose not. Then $a_n \leq N$ for all $n$. This means $\sup_n a_n \leq N <+\infty$, a contradiction. Hence for some some $a_k > N$, call the index $k = n_{N}$. Then define $b_N = a_{k} = a_{n_N}$.

Comment: Okay so since $\sup_n a_n = \infty$ Then its goes that $\sup_n a_n > N \in \mathbb{N}$, now we set $k = N$ therefore $b_N = a_{n_N}$   Now that last part $\lim \inf_N b_N \ge \infty$ Is that saying that the inf of the limit or inf of the sequence.

Comment: No. Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ be fixed. Since $\sup_n a_n > N$, it means **there exists** some $k$ such that $a_k > N$. **Define** $n_N = k$. Then by definition $a_{n_N} > N$.

Comment: So its like $\forall N > 0, \exists k$ such that when $a_n > N,$ then $n \ge k$ hence just $n=k$ Then you let $k = n_N$ so $a_k = b_N = a_{n_N} > N$ So are we saying the the sub-sequence consist of all $b_k$ that $a_k > N$    Basically are we taking only a sub-sequence of elemets where $a_n > \infty$

Comment: No: for all $N$, there exists $k$ such that $a_k > N$.

Comment: See my answer above for more detail.

Comment: for all N, that is N is choose some any natural number, there will always exist some k, were $a_k > N$ then $k=n_N$ so that our sub-sequence of a is equal to this other sequence that we know approaches infinity.

Comment: Please read my edited answer above. It gives you exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach seems OK to me.

0) $\sup a_n=\infty$:  There is no upper bound $L \in \mathbb{R}$, $L >0$ for $a_n$.

Need to show that there is a subsequence $a_{n_k} \rightarrow \infty$.

1) $a_n$ is not bounded above:

For every  $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there is an index $n_{k}$ s.t.

$a_{n_k} >k$.

We show:

The subsequence $a_{n_k}$ converges to $\infty$;

A) For every $L \in \mathbb{R}$, $L >0$, there is, by the Archimedean principle, a

$k_0 \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, s.t. $k_0 >L$.

B) For $k \ge k_0$ :  $n_{k} \ge n_{k_0}$, and

$a_{n_k} \gt k_0> L$, and we are done.

Comment: Can you clarify how we get from $a_{b_k} > k$ to an increasing monotone sequence? Specifically claiming there must exists $k_0 \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $k_0 > L$   Like why $k_0,$ and isnt $\mathbb{Z}^+ = \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Dakota.Edited last line, removed $a_{n_k}>a_{n_{k_0}}$. $L >0$ real! given, there is a integer!, $k_0, ( >0 )$with $k_0 >L$. You need the integer $k_0$ to get to $a_{n_{k_0}} >k_0$.Recall the definition: $a_n $ converges to $\infty$, if for $L>0$, real!, there is an $N$, s.t. for $n\ge N$ $a_n >L$.Your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is trivial, but to prove it ;

$\sup{a_n}=\infty$ means $(\not\exists M)\ a_n<M$. This implies $(\forall\epsilon,\exists n)\ a_n>\epsilon$, so we can write $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$$

now the proof is complete.